# Android app wont work after restarting pc

Tags: android, authentication, remote-server

hi i am currently working in our android project.. and my code works fine last night before i went to bed.. after openning it again.. it cannot even execute my loginpage activity..

this is my loginpage.java

`

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class LoginPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText username, password;
    private Button mSubmit;
    private ToggleButton mShowPass;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // php login script location:

    // localhost :
    // testing on your device
    // put your local ip instead, on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    // or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
    // private static final String LOGIN_URL =
    // "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";

    // testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.10.4/NurseStation/android/physicianlogin.php";

    // testing from a real server:
    // private static final String LOGIN_URL =
    // "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/login.php";

    // JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);
        // setup input fields
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);

        // setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mShowPass = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.showPassword);

        // listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mShowPass.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;

        case R.id.showPassword:
            if (mShowPass.isChecked()) {
                password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                        | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            } else {
                password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginPage.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username
                        .getText().toString().trim()));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password
                        .getText().toString().trim()));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginPage.this);
                    Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("username", username.getText().toString().trim());
                    edit.commit();

                    Intent OpenMainActivity = new Intent(
                            "info.androidhive.slidingmenu.OPENMAINACTIVITY");
                    OpenMainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    OpenMainActivity.putExtra("EXIT", false);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(OpenMainActivity);

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else if (success != 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

`

and this is my php code since my code is connected to my remote server..

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
//require("config.inc.php");

//mysql_connect("localhost","androidapp","RZDJ45xzvfzuTf6C");
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("myhs");

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query_search = "SELECT * FROM physicians WHERE physicianUsername = '".$username."' AND physicianPassword = '".$password. "'";
    //$query_search = "SELECT * FROM physicians ";
    $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());

    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
    //echo $rows;
     if($rows == 0) { 
        //echo "No Such User Found";
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
        die(json_encode($response));
     }
     else  {
        //echo "User Found";
        //save session
        //$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['username'];

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

?>
```

and these are the errors i got..

```
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.LoginPage$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginPage.java:143)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.LoginPage$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginPage.java:1)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061):    ... 5 more
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061): Activity info.androidhive.slidingmenu.LoginPage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42156cd8 that was originally added here
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity info.androidhive.slidingmenu.LoginPage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42156cd8 that was originally added here
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:321)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:234)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:153)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:559)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:301)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.LoginPage$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(LoginPage.java:120)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.LoginPage.onClick(LoginPage.java:89)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17318)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-25 23:49:50.734: E/WindowManager(16061):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me... :'(

Comment: **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 02-25 23:49:41.824: E/AndroidRuntime(16061): at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.LoginPage$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(LoginPage.java:143)**

Comment: highlight your LoginPage.jav‌​a: line 143

Comment: Also **please** do read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) about preventing SQL injection.

Comment: did you check the internet connection, your response is null i think - json.toString , in log.d

Comment: have you start your xampp or lamp ???

Comment: looks a null JSONObject instance .. **not sure about the line number** (line nos may change depending on the formattig ) .

Comment: hi thanks for all the reply... i finally solved the problem... this problem was solved by simply uninstalling the adblock plus in all my browsers... 

http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/02/13/google-has-effectively-killed-adblock-plus-in-android-4-2-2/

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions posted above but it didnt work.. i finally resorted to uninstalling my xampp and reinstalling it again but it didnt work also.. but after 3 hours my app works again after closing and opening my eclipse for several times... i restarted my pc and run the app again to see if it works fine but it gives the same problem.. so i decided to search for problems related to my post.. and i found this blog **strong text** and tried to uninstall the adblock plus installed on all my browsers (mozilla firefox, google chrome, and opera) and it works fine.. :D